# How to set different `expires` values for different php files

Tags: nginx

Since nginx did not add any `expires` headers to my rendered PHP pages (e.g. example.com opens index.php), I've added the following to my config:

```
# PHP proxy
location ~* \.php$ {
  expires         -1;
  try_files       $uri =404;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
  include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params_env;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Now I've got the problem that I have a `img.php` file which resizes and caches images. This script returns the image directly (e.g. `image/jpeg`) so it should expire much later.

How can I differentiate between different PHP files?

Comment: The PHP application should set the header.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense ... since I'm running WordPress, I could add the correct header to the `wp-config.php`?

Comment: If it's a WP plugin, yell at the plugin developer.

Comment: It's `cimage` which I just "installed" to the root, so it isn't a plugin.

Comment: This one: https://github.com/mosbth/cimage

Comment: Well, that one lets you set the cache-control header in its config file. So you still don't need to mess with nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally your web application should be managing its own cache control headers. But in case it does not, you can use [`expires`](https://nginx.org/r/expires) to do so in nginx.

In this circumstance, you can use a `map` to set different values based on the content type that will be sent. For example:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default             -1;
    application/rss+xml off;
    application/pdf     max;
    ~image/             365d;
}
```

Of course, you should change those to what you actually want.

Then in your `expires` directive, use the variable you have set:

```
    expires $expires;
```

Comment: Awww, works like a charm! Before, I've set the headers with different `location` blocks, but this one is great.